# How to decode a 16-bit ASCII data to an integer when you have it in a string of 2 characters in python using struct module?

Tags: python, codec, wave

Here is my code. **Ideally both struct.unpack and encode('hex') and changing it back to int should be the same right?**

INPUT -

> But, they are **not** the same in this case when you give a .wav file with nchannels = 1, samplewidth = 2, framerate = 44100, comptype = "None", compname = "Not compressed"

SAMPLE OUTPUT -

> -15638  ==  eac2  ==  27330
>
> -15302  ==  3ac4  ==  15044
>
> -14905  ==  c7c5  ==  18373
>
> -14449  ==  8fc7  ==  4039
>
> *The left and right hand-side should be equal right?*

```
import wave
import sys
import struct

audiofile = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
# reading a file (normal file open)

print audiofile.getparams()
# (nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname)

for i in range(audiofile.getnframes()):
    frame = audiofile.readframes(1)
    # reading each frame (Here frame is 16 bits [.wav format of each frame])

    print struct.unpack('<h', frame)[0], ' == ',
    # struct.unpack(fmt, string) --- for more info about fmt -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html
    # If we it is two samples per frame, then we get a tuple with two values -> left and right samples

    value = int(frame.encode('hex'), 16)
    # getting the 16-bit value [each frame is 16 bits]

    if(value > 32767):
        value -= 2**16
    # because wav file format specifies 2's compliment as in even the negative values are there

    print frame.encode('hex') , ' == ', value

audiofile.close()
```

Comment: Something appears to be wrong with your indentation. Please fix?

Comment: Also not sure what your question is. Maybe you can give a shorter snippet of code, share its output, and share what output you expected.

Comment: @smarx I've added a sample output. My main question is if I encode frame to hex and convert back to int type and if I use struct module to directly get the value of 16-bits in int type - They should be equal right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is between big-endian and little-endian encoding.

Your struct is big-endian, while the conversion with hex is little-endian.

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html, using '<' means it is little-endian